# Proof Verification: Suppose $X$ is a metric space and $S\subseteq X$. Then $\partial (\partial S)\subseteq \partial S$

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

The book by Michael Searcoid gave a different proof so I want to know where I made an error.

Proof:
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $S\subset X$. By definition, 
\begin{align}
\partial S:=\{x\in X\quad\vert\quad dist(x,S)=0=dist(x,S^c)\}\\
\partial(\partial S):={y\in X\quad\vert\quad dist(y,\partial S)=0=dist(y,(\partial S)^c)}
\end{align}
Suppose $\alpha\in\partial(\partial S)$, then $dist(\alpha,\partial S)=0=dist(\alpha, (\partial S)^c)$; that is
\begin{align}
\exists\sigma\in\partial S\quad s.t.\quad d(\alpha,\sigma)=inf\{d(\alpha,\overline{\sigma})\quad\vert\quad\overline{\sigma}\in\partial S\}=0\\
\exists\sigma'\in(\partial S)^c\quad s.t.\quad d(\alpha,\sigma')=inf\{d(\alpha, \sigma')\quad\vert\quad \sigma'\in(\partial S)^c\}=0
\end{align}
But, $d(\alpha,\sigma)=0=d(\alpha,\sigma')$ iff $\alpha=\sigma$ and $\alpha=\sigma'$. Therefore, $\sigma=\sigma'=\alpha\in\partial S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you wrote $\alpha\in\partial S$, I suppose that you meant that $\alpha\in\partial(\partial S)$.

The error lies in assuming that if the distance of a point $\alpha$ to a set $A$ is $0$, then $\alpha\in A$. This is not true. For instance, in $\mathbb R$, with the usual distance, $d\bigl(0,(0,+\infty)\bigr)=0$, but $0\notin(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Yes it is what I meant to write. Understood, but the book's definition of distance is $dist(\alpha,\partial S):=inf\{d(\alpha,\sigma)\vert \sigma\in\partial S\}$

Comment: I think the example you gave explains the motivation of the proof from the book. Did I misunderstand the definition of distance perhaps?

Comment: I don't understand you question. I used the same definition of distance as you. But you seem to believe that it follows from the definition that $d(\alpha,A)=0\implies\alpha\in A$. It doesn't.